# Installing Django when Python is already installed through Anaconda?

Tags: python, django

I am having the common issue when trying to run:

```
django-admin startproject hellodjango
```

that I am getting the error:

```
'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have run:

```
pip install Django
```

Which ran successfully. However, when I navigate to my C:\Python 3\Scripts folder, I don't see any djangoadmin.py or related files in there.

Python 3 is added as a PATH environmental variable.

When I run:

```
python --version
```

I get the following:

```
Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep 19 2017, 08:03:39)
```

Could my issue potentially be that my version of python is actually within the Anaconda package, rather than an explicit standalone python installation? (Just a guess as i'm not sure where i'm going wrong).

Comment: Try to use virualenv to isolate the dependency for your project instead of installing every package globally, check this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

Comment: when you use anaconda its better to use conda instead of pip because pip can mess up in anaconda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django-admin is probably missing from your path in that case...

You could try running with the full path. C:\Python 3\site-packages\django\bin\django-admin

To fix, edit your path to include the path above.

Comment: Hi spitfire. I don't actually have a site-packages folder in there. I did find a site-packages folder in: C:\Python 3\Lib\site-packages but there is no Django folder in there.

Comment: Okay for generic python that's where it should be....
Check the anaconda location here: C:/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3/...

Comment: You could also try starting that anaconda prompt and running the same command.

Comment: Sorry could you clarify what you mean here? What I was hoping was to use python in a standalone way, and ignore the anaconda installed version (if that makes a difference) as it just feels a lot cleaner.

Comment: To add - I did run the Django-admin command in Anaconda Prompt and still the same issue.

Comment: Okay, so you probably have 2 versions of python: one with Anaconda and one w/o. Django is installed on the anaconda environment. Anaconda can already allow you to have a cleaner environment through the use of virtual environments. Now to run Django-admin you could boot your Anaconda Prompt which installs with Anaconda and run:django-admin startproject hellodjango and you should be fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158882/discussion-between-spitfire21-and-curious-student).

Comment: For anyone wondering, please see discussion in chat. Full path to Django installation was required in order to run.